# How to create a CXR Dataset just like MNIST dataset?

Tags: image, tensorflow, dataset

I have jpeg images of chest radiographs. If i want to feed the data to a deep network what do i need to do ?

I am using tensorflow library in python . I want to provide labels as normal or abnormal.How can i create a dataset like MNIST ?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on this topic. The official introduction to importing data can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets.